# Format text as bold

Tags: excel, vba

This formula colors an entire row based on a cell in that row containing a specific value.

```
For Each Cell In .Range("Y5:" & .Range("Y1500").End(xlDown).Address)
    If .Cells(Cell.Row, 25).value = "Super Project" Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vR(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, n))

    End If
Next
End With
```

How can I make the cell in column “B” also turn bold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bold a cell: `Range.Font.Bold = True`

Your target cell is in `Col Y` (Col 25) so to get to `Col B` (Col 2) you need to go backwards (offset by a value of) 23 columns resulting in:

`Cell.Offset(0,-23).Font.Bold = True`

---

The OCD side of me insists on advising you to

1. Indent Properly
2. Modify the loop range (see code)
3. Column `Y` = Column `25`. No need for `.Cells(Cell.Row, 25)`. Just analyze the variable, `Cell`
4. Last, distinguishing between `Cells` the **Object** and `Cell` the **Variable** you declared can be confusing and lead to errors. Change `Cell` to something like `MyCell` so the difference is clear.

---

```
Dim MyCell as Range

With Sheets(1) 'Some Sheet
    For Each MyCell In .Range("Y5:Y" & .Range("Y" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If MyCell = "Super Project" Then
            MyCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vR(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, n))
            MyCell.Offset(,-23).Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next
End With
```

Comment: That works perfect, thanks! I really do appreciate the clear, concise explanation, as I am very new to VBA. I also appreciate the "OCD" comment... I tend to be that way too, but I am still figuring this out! Thanks!